# Swift - How to I define a special method for my class that returns a string representation of its object

Tags: python, swift, syntactic-sugar

In python if you want to define a string representation of an object you can do the following:

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first} {self.last}, {self.age} years old'

person_1 = Person('John', 'Smith', 25)
```

Now, if you write `print(person_1)` or `str(person_1)`, then you get `John Smith, 25 years old`.

If the `__str__` method didn't exist, then the output would be `<__main__.Person object at 0x104e12e20>`

***How do I do the same thing in swift?***

sure, I could define a method with whatever name I want and then call it on the object, but it would lack syntactic sugar.

Comment: Make your class/struct conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol. That should do what you need.

Comment: I'm new to swift and I haven't used protocols before. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Sure thing. See below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. All you have to do is implement the `description` property.

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    var description: String {
        return "[name: \(name), age: \(age)]"
    }
}

print(Person(name: "bob", age: 32)) // [name: bob, age: 32]
```